# Disconnect on Token Expiry

Tags: firebase

I'm trying to make the presence & token expiry a little more resilient in my app.

My presence table creates a record on login with the login timestamp and then when the user closes the session the server records to logout timestamp via the onDisconnect() function.

However, when the auth token expires it does not automatically disconnect the session and as such my presence indicator still shows the user is online. Furthermore, if a user then reconnects on the same browser it looks as if the user is logged in twice as it still has not recorded the onDisconnect from the first session.

Should the expiry of the auth token automatically disconnect the session or am I meant to watch for the disconnect and disconnect the session myself?

Comment: You are talking about two different things here. One is your connection to the Firebase hosted service, which is a simple WebSocket or XHR based connection. The other is authenticated state, which is unrelated to the first. Monitor .info/authenticated for changes in auth state rather than trying to monitor the socket connection, and manually set your user offline is this is your desired use case.

Answer (score 2):

There is different between authentication and connection. You can listen at  /.info/authenticated for authenticate-state ([Firebase docs](https://www.firebase.com/docs/managing-presence.html)).

The problem should be when your onDisconnect operation needs auth rights - because of security rules.

Answer (score 0):

All firebase auth tokens have an expiry time, this is returned to you in the authlistener. You can disconnect after this expiry time is passed. I am unsure what language/API you are using towards firebase, but the APIs are mostly the same between android/ios/web.